# get auto-genearated key for the inserted record in mybatis

Tags: spring-mvc, mybatis

I am working under a web application which use spring mvc + mybatis + mysql.

And I found that I can not get the auto-generated key for the last inserted record (I have googled so much).

This is the related configuration(take the model 'Post' for example):

#### spring.xml:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    //omitted
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="config.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

#### mybatis config.xml

```
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias alias="Post" type="com.king.model.Post" />
    </typeAliases>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="com/king/model/PostMapper.xml" />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

#### PostMapper.xml:

```
<mapper namespace="com.king.model.PostMapper">
    <insert id="insert" parameterType="Post">
        insert into posts (title,body,created_at,updated_at) values (#{title},#{body},#{createDate},#{updateDate})
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

#### Dao:

```java
public abstract class AbstractSimpleDaoImpl<T> extends SqlSessionDaoSupport{
    @Override
    public int add(T entity) {
        return getSqlSession().insert(getMapperNamespace() + ".insert", entity);
    }

    protected abstract String getMapperNamespace();
}

public class PostDao extends AbstractSimpleDaoImpl<Post> {
    @Override
    protected String getMapperNamespace() {
        return "com.king.model.PostMapper";
    }
}
```

---

However,when I insert a new Post to database:

```java
postDao.add(post);
```

I can not get the generated id for the inserted post. I always get 1. I know this is the row-affected number.

Also,I read the mybatis guide,and I tried this:

```xml
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Post" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
```

But it seems that,this does not work.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In fact the following works:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Post" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">

postDao.add(post);
```

will return 1 as before,but `post.getId()` will get the key.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done using annotations as well.

```
final String INSERT = "insert into posts (title,body,created_at,updated_at) values (#{title},#{body},#{createDate},#{updateDate})";

@Insert(INSERT)
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "id")
void insert(Post post) throws Exception;
```

Set `keyProperty` as the Java variable name.

Set `keyColumn` as the column name in the database.

After insert, `post.getId()` will have your generated ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code; I added the **keyColumn** field to your code:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Post" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id">
```

Alternatively, if you are using *PostgreSql*:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Post" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id"> 
<selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="java.lang.Integer">
        SELECT
        currVal('your_tbl_seq') as id
    </selectKey> </insert>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for Spring Boot using annotations and getting the `id` as a return value as in your original question.

```
@Insert("insert into sources (host, created_at) values (#{host}, now())")
@SelectKey(statement="select LAST_INSERT_ID()", keyProperty="id", before=false, resultType=long.class)
long create(@Param("host") String host);
```

Then `long id = sourceMapper.create("abc");` would return your primary key.